# Manga about a girl who went back in time to her wedding night

Tags: story-identification, manga

I'm looking for a manga that I stumbled upon on IG sometimes ago. I don't remember the title. All I know is that it's a manga about a woman who went back in time to her wedding night. Before she went back in time, she received a message that her husband died.

I also remember these 2 points I'm not sure if my brain is tricking me or something.

1. They were in a political marriage.
2. Their marriage lasted for 3 months before the husband died.

Comment: What does "IG" stands for? Since you mentioned that you stumbled on it, Is it a manga or an anime? Also, could you give an estimate of when you saw it?

Answer (score 2):

***[The Tyrant Husband Has Changed](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/bo7fn6k/my-husband-s-reversal)***; this is the name of the manga.

From Baka-Updates:

> On death’s doorstep after being stabbed by an assassin, the one thing Idris is sure of is that she doesn’t want to die. Her fate seems sealed until her husband Khalid, the terrifying archduke of Caltes, makes a cryptic promise to save her life. That’s when Idris wakes up a year earlier, on the day of her wedding, with a chance to redo it all. But while she’s grateful to be alive, her memories aren’t adding up. The Khalid she remembers was a ruthless tyrant, but the man before her now is affectionate and kind. Was their loveless marriage just a horrible dream or has Idris’s past become twisted in reality? She has no choice but to trust Khalid’s heart if she wants to survive and find out who tried to kill her.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to explain why you think this might be the correct manga, i.e. the ways in which it matches the one described in the question.